# Which test should I use to compare two binomial variables measured in same subject?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, paired-data

For example, let's imagine I measured two binary variable in my subject: 1) SUV or not SUV, 2) Speeding or not speeding (similar to a 2x2 contingency table). Let's say I hypothesized that SUV are less likely to speed than non-SUV.

Which test would allow me to test my hypothesis? Would it be possible to obtain a confidence interval?

The closest test I can think of is McNemar's test, but it only test for equality and not "less than" hypothesis.

Comment: https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman1/auxillar/mcnemar.htm

Comment: "one sided barnard's test"

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options. I'll describe each and then give you some key words to look for in searching for more about them.

1. You could run a logistic regression, predicting speeding from whether or not the person was in an SUV. However, since your observations are *not* independent (i.e., some came from the same people), your standard errors are going to be biased. A way to address this is to fit a logistic regression and then adjust the standard errors using what are called "sandwich estimators" (they are called that because the matrix notation looks like a sandwich). These can also be called "robust standard errors" and are often used when referring to clustered or panel data.
2. You could fit a generalized estimating equation (GEE) with a logistic link function. This is similar to the first option, but you are using a different method of estimation and you specify how you think the errors are correlated with one another (in practice, this choice seems to not matter a whole lot, but is still necessary to make beforehand).
3. You could fit a multilevel model/mixed effects model with a logistic link function. This is similar to the two above, except now you are modeling variances a little differently. Instead of just treating the dependencies as noise, you can model these variances (such as random intercepts or slopes). You would not be able to model the random effect/variance around the effect of SUV or not if you only had two observations per person, though, because that model isn't identified (i.e., you don't have enough observations for each person in both conditions to model variance in the effect of condition). Since you are mainly interested in the effect of condition and not other aspects, then this might not be the best fit for you—but it is a popular option.

You can calculate confidence intervals for any of the above options.

(Note that I kept referring to logistic regression because it's the canonical link function, but there are other options you might see out there, such as a probit link function).

To get background on logistic regression in general, look into "generalized linear models." Searching for "robust standard errors" or "sandwich estimators" will get you more information on #1. Searching for "generalized estimating equations" or "GEE" will get you more information for #2. And people refer the #3 as multilevel models/mixed effects models/hierarchical models interchangeably. You'd want to look for information on models that are generalized mixed effects models, etc., because you are looking for generalizing it to dichotomous outcomes.

If you are an R user, #1 is `sandwich` package, #2 is `gee` or `geepack` packages, and #3 is `lme4` or `nlme` packages.

Comment: I disagree that there are dependent observations; I think each car has a single record (row) and that this is more of a bread-and-butter case than you have described.  Maybe your answer could cover that possibility as well as the more complex one you've addressed.

Comment: @rolando2 the title says that the observations are measured in the same subject, so the dependency is in the person driving the car. Each person has more than one row. The tag also says paired data.

Comment: I recommend you change the title from "...compare two binomial variables..." to "...compare two binomial variables for multiple observations..." and that you add "Each person has more than one row" to the main body of the question.

Comment: The pairs $(x_i, y_i) $ are independent from each other if subject refers to the index $i$. And the 'within subject' stuff just refers to the pairing. Without this interpretation (pairing such that there are four possible values) the 2x2 contingency table makes no sense.

Comment: I probably misunderstood the question, then. I read it as the outcome, speeding, is measured multiple times in the same person. Mods can feel free to delete if OP confirms observations are iid.

Comment: I am not sure who misunderstood the question. There can still be repetition  and dependence, e.g. when these data represent the random measurements of car speeds on a road, and the same car may possibly pass multiple times.